# How do I turn off the feature on my MacBook Air that highlights all texts when the mouse points to that text?

Tags: mouse, text

I am using macOS Catalina version 10.15.7. Everytime I move my mouse to any text, that text automatically gets highlighted in a display box.  This is a very annoying feature.  How can I turn this feature off?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of this?

Answer (score 2):

Disable the Hover Text accessibility feature in **System Preferences** > **Accessibility** > **Zoom** > **Enable Hover Text**.